How to open PDF in ANSA
I am looking for a way to open a PDF file to view it with python through the ANSA script editor.
Any way I go about this?  It will show no errors but it also doesn't open the PDF file.
I was wondering if anyone knew how to get around this problem. I am running from a Linux. Thanks!
Existing Code:
import os
import subprocess
import platform

file_path = "RUNME.pdf"

if platform.system() == "Windows":
        os.startfile(file_path)
elif platform.system() == "Darwin":
    subprocess.Popen(['open', file_path])
else:
    #my_env = os.environ.copy()
    #if 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH' in my_env:
    #   del my_env ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH']
    subprocess.Popen(['xdg-open', file_path])


A buddy of mine figured it out but my reasoning of it is lacking.
from ansa import base, guitk, utils
import os
import subprocess
 
def open_documentation(btn, dummy):
   doc_path = "RUNME.pdf"
   if not os.path.exists(doc_path):
       utils.PrintToConsole(f"Error: File not found at {doc_path}")
       return
   try:
       # Copy of the current environment variables
       ef_env = os.environ.copy()
       # Get rid of ANSA library paths that may interfere w/ external applications like firefox
       for var in ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH', 'PYTHONPATH', 'PATH']:
           if var in ef_env:
               del ef_env[var]
       subprocess.Popen(['xdg-open', doc_path], env=ef_env)
   except Exception as e:
       # Print error's to ANSA's console for debugging
       utils.PrintToConsole(f"Error opening file: {e}")
       base.MessageBoxError(f"Error opening documentation: {str(e)}")
 
window = guitk.BCWindowCreate("Documentation Helper", guitk.constants.BCOnExitDestroy)
main_frame = guitk.BCFrameCreate(window)
button = guitk.BCPushButtonCreate(main_frame, "Open Documentation", open_documentation)
guitk.BCShow(window)

Apparently, by removing ANSA's library paths in the env variables, firefox looks in its regular system location for those libraries, allowing it to function.
